Dynamically pass file name to FTP task in Realisable Iman
I want to generate a dynamic file name and pass it to the 'Remote file' fied of an FTP task in Realisable Iman.  I have used a script task (Vb) to generate the file name but I can't find away to pass that file name into the target field on the FTP Task.
I declared a Dim variable  having resaecrhed that it will be global and tried to access it from the FTP task input field but it dint work.
I also defiend a function that i tried to call inside the FTP input field but it dont work.
My confusion comes fromwhat the correct syntax is and whether this is done the way i am tring.
the syntaxes i tried are
$filename, %filename%, ${filename} but none have worked.
I am using Iman version 5.1
